# How to use Cancellation Token properly in this code?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a GUI application where data is continously polled by MyMethod and when the Disconnect button is clicked, inside MyMethod the OperationCanceledException
closes the port. Here my_cancelationTokenSource is declared:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
private CancellationTokenSource my_cancelationTokenSource;

//...
}
```

And here MyMethod continously polls data:

```
private async Task MyMethod(ISerialComms port, byte[] test_telegram)
{
    byte[] sent;

    my_cancelationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    try
    {
        do
        {
            await Task.Delay(POLL_PERIOD, my_cancelationTokenSource.Token);


            if (myFlag == false && sent != null && myPort.IsOpen == true && test_port == false)
            {

                byte[] received = await telegram.SendReceive(sent, myPort, port, my_cancelationTokenSource.Token);
                MyProgressMethod(received, sent);

            }


        }
        while (true);
    }

    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        try
        {
            my_cancelationTokenSource.Dispose();
            my_cancelationTokenSource = null;

            if (myPort.IsOpen)
            {
                myPort.Close();
            }

        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Here is the disconnect button:

```
private void Button_Disconnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    my_cancelationTokenSource?.Cancel();

}
```

And below I have another async method TestParameters() run in series inside another button:

```
private async void Test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (myPort.IsOpen)
        {
            myFlag = true;

            byte[] set_parameter = myObject.CreatePulseParameters((double)NumericUpDown1.Value, (double)NumericUpDown2.Value);

            int delay_ms = 20;

            await Task.Delay(delay_ms);
            await TestParameters(set_parameter);

            await Task.Delay(delay_ms * 2);
            await TestParameters(set_parameter);

            await Task.Delay(delay_ms);
            await TestParameters(set_parameter);

            await Task.Delay(delay_ms * 4);
            await TestParameters(set_parameter);

            await Task.Delay(delay_ms);
            await TestParameters(set_parameter);

            await Task.Delay(delay_ms);
            await TestParameters(set_parameter);
            
            await Task.Delay(delay_ms * 3);
            await TestParameters(set_parameter);

            myFlag = false;
        }
    }

    catch (System.InvalidOperationException)
    {
        myPort.Close();
    }
}
```

My problem is, when I click Disconnect the port is closed but TestParameters() keeps running. How can this issue be solved?
(One solution was to put if(myPort.IsOpen) before each TestParameters(), but somehow I thought there misght be a more reilable better way)

Wht I need: TestParameters() should stop running as well when the Disconnect button is clicked just like MyMetho().

**Edit:**
Two other Tasks:

```
private async Task TestParameters(byte[] set_parameter)
{
    if (myPort.IsOpen)
    {
        int times_try = 5;
        int retry = 0;
        myFlag = true;
        await Task.Delay(500);

        do
        {
            bool validate = await Set_Parameters(set_parameter);
            await Task.Delay(500);

            if (validate)
                break;

            if (!validate)
                retry++;
        }
        while (retry < times_try);


    }

    myFlag = false;
}
```

And the other one:

```
private async Task<bool> Set_Parameters(byte[] send_set_parameter_telegram)
{
    bool validate = false;      

    byte[] validate_parameters = pulse.validate_parameters;

    if (myPort.IsOpen )
    {


        await Task.Delay(100);
        byte[] receive_error_telegram = await telegram.SendReceive(validate_parameters, myPort, port);
        await Task.Delay(100);
        byte[] receive_validated_telegram = await telegram.SendReceive(validate_parameters, myPort, port);



    }

    return validate;

}
```

[image: error]

Comment: Why would not you use the same technique as in `MyMethod` passing cancellation token to every async method in  `Test_Click` ?

Comment: Also, I guess `myPort` is disposable, so I'd use `myPort.Dispose()` method.

Comment: What does myPort.Dispose()  do comparing to myPort.Close()?